# Update rows based on different rows in the same table

Tags: mysql

I use this table to store some keys and I'd like to update the column "value" where the column "name" is equal to name_1 only if the user's country is CA

| user | name | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | name_1 | 0 |
| 1 | country | FR |
| 2 | name_1 | 0 |
| 2 | country | CA |
| 3 | name_1 | 0 |
| 3 | country | CA |

Expected output:

| user | name | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | name_1 | 0 |
| 1 | country | FR |
| 2 | name_1 | **1** |
| 2 | country | CA |
| 3 | name_1 | **1** |
| 3 | country | CA |

I think I can do this using a stored procedure, but I don't know if there's an easier way to do it using a single query. Thanks

This is the stored procedure I created, it works but I really would love to execute something more simple.

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE updateName1()
BEGIN
    DECLARE done BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE userId INT;

    -- Declare a cursor for the SELECT query
    DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR
        SELECT distinct user FROM my_table WHERE name = 'country' AND value = 'CA';

    -- Declare handler for when no more rows found
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

    -- Open the cursor
    OPEN cur;

    -- Loop through the result set
    read_loop: LOOP
        FETCH cur INTO userId;

        -- Exit loop when no more rows
        IF done THEN
            LEAVE read_loop;
        END IF;

        -- Perform actions with each row here
        -- For example, print the values
        UPDATE my_table SET value = 1 WHERE name = 'name_1' AND user = userId;

    END LOOP;

    -- Close the cursor
    CLOSE cur;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be possible something like this:

```
Update your_table t1 join your_table t2 on t1.user = t2.user
Set value = 1
Where t1.name = 'name_1' and
  t2.name = 'country' and
  t2.value = 'CA'
```